# Angular datatables pagination not working

Tags: angularjs, datatable, pagination

I'm using angular datatable to populate list of users in my application and following this simple [Angular Way](https://l-lin.github.io/angular-datatables/#/angularWay). All code is working fine except the pagination button click. I gives proper numbering according to data but when i click anyone of them, it does not move to that list of data. I've added its libraries and this is my html code

```
<table datatable="ng" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
                  <thead>
                  <tr>
                            <th>User Name</th>
                            <th>First Name</th>
                            <th>Last Name</th>
                            <th>Cell No.</th>
                            <th>Email</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                             <tr ng-repeat="user in allUsers">
                                <td>{{ user.UserName }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.FirstName }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.LastName }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.CellNo }}</td>
                                <td>{{ user.Email }}</td>
                                <td><button type="button" ng-click="btnView_Click(user.Id)" class="btn btn-info"><i class="fa fa-edit"></i> View</button></td>
                              </tr>

                        </tbody>
                    </table>
```

and this is how its showing buttons [image: Pagination] But nothing happens when I click any of these buttons (e.g Prev, 1,2,...Next)

I don't know how to create a fiddle for this. Can anyone have any guesses what I'm missing? and why this is happening??

Comment: And where is your js?

Comment: there's nothing in js except assigning data to allUsers

Comment: There should be logic, for paging at least. There is not a single line related to paging. What did you expect from us?

Comment: @Kindzoku the link which i followed does not have any logic for paging...!!

Comment: @NullPointer, you misread an example. The example in your link only shows data binding to table. There is no logic related to paging. Not even HTML related to paging.

Comment: There is.. *datatable="ng"* in datatable declaration * <table datatable="ng" class="row-border hover">*  is basically render the whole pagination work.

Comment: and yeah I missed the reference of datatables js.. that was mentioned at the start of link

Comment: Well... I don't know what do you need this library for, but here I wrote a plunker for you. The pagination the most Angular way: https://plnkr.co/edit/kmQcpSWGxPNIvJUfcQF0?p=preview It's so easy, you don't really need any side library.

Comment: Added sorting. Check please.

Comment: "_But nothing happens when I click any of these buttons (e.g Prev, 1,2,...Next)_"  - my fist impulse is that you have an invisible overlapping element preventing the pagination buttons from receiving clicks. When the pagination buttons is rendered you do have pagination, period :) There is simply no reason for this to fail ....

Comment: I don't know what the issue was.. but I just replaced the css and js file of *angular-datatables.min* and my issue just blown away,,, I guess it was configuration issue